# Alternate colback and colbacklower in tcblisting

Tags: listings, color, pgfkeys, tcolorbox

I have written a new environment based on `tcblisting` from package `tcolorbox`. I want the background color for code always in "gray" and the background color of the text compiled in "white".

He held four options, but in a couple of them I switch the values ​​of `colback` and `colbacklower`. This is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,breakable,skins}
% tcolorbox settings
\tcbset{
myexample/.style={breakable,skin=bicolor,%
                colback=lightgray,%
                colframe=gray,%
                colbacklower=white,%
                title style={draw=none,fill=none}%
                }%
}% 
% Create myexample enviroment 
\newtcblisting{myexample}[1]{myexample,#1}
\begin{document}
% listing=colback, text=colbacklower OK
\begin{myexample}{listing and text}
The background color of the source code should be in gray.
The background color for text compiled in white.
\end{myexample}
% listing=colbacklower, text=colback Wrong, need listing=colback,text=colbacklower
\begin{myexample}{text and listing}
The background color of the source code should be in gray.
The background color for text compiled in white.
\end{myexample}
% listing=colbacklower, text=colback Wrong, need listing=colback,text=colbacklower 
\begin{myexample}{text side listing}
The background color of the source code should be in gray.
The background color for text compiled in white.
\end{myexample}
% listing=colbacklower, text=colback OK
\begin{myexample}{listing side text}
The background color of the source code should be in gray.
The background color for text compiled in white.
\end{myexample}
\end{document}
```

And here are my two questions:

1. It is possible to automatically define the environment?
2. How to define an alias for "listing and text", "text and listing", "listing side text" and "text side listing", like `keyval` options (pgfkeys maybe?).

   something like:

   ```
   listing and text=top
   text and listing=below
   listing side text=left
   text side listing=right
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tcolorbox` uses the `pgfkeys` engine and you may add your own options the same way you made `myexample`. For your question, an answer is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,breakable,skins}
% tcolorbox settings
\tcbset{
above/.style={colback=lightgray,colbacklower=white,listing and text},
below/.style={colback=white,colbacklower=lightgray,text and listing},
left/.style={colback=lightgray,colbacklower=white,listing side text},
right/.style={colback=white,colbacklower=lightgray,text side listing},
%
myexample/.style={breakable,skin=bicolor,
                  above,%
                  colframe=gray,%
                  title style={draw=none,fill=none}%
                  }%
}%
% Create myexample enviroment
\newtcblisting{myexample}[1]{myexample,#1}
\begin{document}
% default:
\begin{myexample}{above}
The background color of the source code should be in gray.
The background color for text compiled in white.
\end{myexample}

\begin{myexample}{below}
The background color of the source code should be in gray.
The background color for text compiled in white.
\end{myexample}

\begin{myexample}{right}
The background color of the source code should be in gray.
The background color for text compiled in white.
\end{myexample}

\begin{myexample}{left}
The background color of the source code should be in gray.
The background color for text compiled in white.
\end{myexample}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks to very much...and if you wanted an alias for like a lefthand ratio=number ===> ratio=number ; and listing options={style=code} ===>style=number,unumber (default unnumber)

Comment: @PabloGonzález You ask for an option with an argument? e.g. `myratio/.style={lefthand ratio=#1,listing options={style=code}}` creates an option to set the `lefthand ratio` with value and some listing options. Section 55 of the `pgfmanual.pdf` (TikZ/pgf documentation) gives all details of the syntax.

Comment: @PabloGonzález by the way: if my answer to your original question is ok for you, you should vote and accept it ...

Comment: I read the documentation, but I'm not familiar with pgf, I can give an example, I have two listing styles "number" and "unnumber", and need creates an option "style = number" and "style = unnumber".

Comment: @PabloGonzález You could add something like `number/.style={listing options={style=number}}` and `unnumber/.style={listing options={style=unnumber}}` to switch the styles easily by `number` and `unnumber`.

Comment: '@ Thomas F. Sturm':Is posible to create the "alias" to "above" is the same as "pos = t".

Comment: @PabloGonzález I think you should ask this as a new question with some MWE or sketch what you want to do. This will allow me (or somebody faster than me) to give an answer with more room as inside a comment.